# Redux Form - Can't get "Initialize from state" example to work - TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a form (redux-form) that works just fine. I'm trying to merge `defaultInitialValues` with a map I have in my redux state, I've tried the official example (https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/initializefromstate/) but I can't get it to work.

Here is the working code (without getting the map from state):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getFormSyncErrors, getFormValues, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class SimulatorForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //...
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}

const defaultInitialValues = {
  name: 'john doe',
};

// Bind redux-form values as props for this form.
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return ({
    values: getFormValues('simulator')(state),
    errors: getFormSyncErrors('simulator')(state),
  });
};

export default compose(
  reduxForm({
    form: 'simulator',
    initialValues: defaultInitialValues,
  }),
  connect(mapStateToProps),
)(SimulatorForm);
```

By following the example, I tried to do the following (end of file):

```js
// Decorate with reduxForm(). It will read the initialValues prop provided by connect()
SimulatorForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'simulator', // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimulatorForm);

// You have to connect() to any reducers that you wish to connect to yourself
SimulatorForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: { ...defaultInitialValues, ...{ institution: 'tata' } },
  }),
  connect(mapStateToProps),
)(SimulatorForm);

export default SimulatorForm;
```

But I get

> TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
>   _classCallCheck
>   node_modules/react-redux/es/components/connectAdvanced.js:3

I'm probably missing something simple but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the solution after writing the whole question and decided to post a question/answer instead of deleting it, I hope it helps other people!

```js
const defaultInitialValues = {
  name:'john doe',
};

// Bind redux-form values as props for this form.
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return ({
    values: getFormValues('simulator')(state),
    errors: getFormSyncErrors('simulator')(state),
  });
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  goToStep2: () => dispatch({
    type: 'GO_TO_STEP_2',
  }),
});

// XXX If your Form depends on state values (like mine does), you MUST load them BEFORE loading the form itself, or they'll be undefined and your app will likely crash 
SimulatorForm = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SimulatorForm);

// Decorate with reduxForm(). It will read the initialValues prop provided by connect()
// XXX See https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/initializefromstate/
SimulatorForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'simulator', // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimulatorForm);

// Here happens the magic, getting values from state and merging them with default values
export default connect(
  state => {
    const initialValuesFromSettings = state.simulator.settings.modules.formInitialValues.enabled === true ?
      state.simulator.settings.modules.formInitialValues.values
      : {};

    return {
      initialValues: { ...defaultInitialValues, ...initialValuesFromSettings },
    };
  },
)(SimulatorForm);
```